# Is the quotient of a variety over $\mathbb{Q}$ by a finite group still defined over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a variety defined over $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $G$ be a finite group that acts on the complex points of $X$, i.e. $X(\mathbb{C})$. Then over $\mathbb{C}$, the quotient $X/G$ is well defined. Is this quotient $X/G$ defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ in general? If not, in which case is it defined over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: The torsion of $ \text{Aut}(\mathbb{C}(t_1,\ldots,t_d))$ should be defined over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. In that case $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}(X)_{gal}/\overline{\mathbb{Q}}(X)/ \overline{\mathbb{Q}}(t_1,\ldots,t_d)/\overline{\mathbb{Q}}(t_1,\ldots,t_d)^G$ is a finite Galois extension and $G$ is a subgroup of its Galois group. 
Thus $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}(X)_{gal}^G$ makes sense and it contains  $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}(X/G)$, and $X/G$ is defined over $K $ the number field containing all the coefficients defining those fields.